# Is there a way to use a cleaner to omit specific cases? (R)

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe where I want to omit cases where ages 30 or less are omitted. I know you can use na.omit to omit NA cases, but how would I omit specific cases like this?

Comment: Please refer to this for a good question and easy to understand, so others can understand your question thorougly.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you show some example input, and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be more a filtering problem than omitting missing values:

```
> df <- tibble(age = c(20,25,30,35,40))
> 
> df %>% filter(age < 30)
# A tibble: 2 × 1
    age
  <dbl>
1    20
2    25
>
```

Answer (score 0):

With base R, you can filter out all rows where the age is greater than 50.

```
df[df$age < 30,]

    age values
  <int>  <dbl>
1    21  1.89 
2    22  1.01 
3    23  0.107
4    24  1.46 
5    25  1.17 
6    26  1.86 
7    27  1.77 
8    28  1.91 
9    29  0.594
```

Or with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(df)
dt[age < 30]
```

However, if you are wanting to only filter `NA`s for the rows, where the age is greater than 30, then you can find the row index for age being greater than 30 and another column having `NA`. Then, you can exclude those rows.

```
df[!(df$age > 30 & is.na(df$values)),]
```

Or with `subset`:

```
subset(df, !(age > 30 & is.na(values)))
```

With `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  filter(!(age > 30 & is.na(values)))
```

`data.table`:

```
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[!(age > 30 & is.na(values))]
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(age = 21:40, 
                     values = c(1.88648780807853, 1.01084147393703, 
                                0.107075828593224, 1.46145519195125, 1.16910230834037, 1.85718628577888, 
                                1.7749991081655, 1.91132036875933, 0.594451983459294, 0.976039483677596, 
                                1.31880497187376, 1.82749796425924, 1.98314357083291, 0.57053042575717, 
                                0.722490054555237, 1.66634088428691, 0.702816031407565, 0.622223159298301, 
                                0.298387756571174, 1.6071562608704)), 
                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```